# Run Coded UI test cases in one instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests, visual-studio-project

I did Coded UI automated test cases for Visual studio extension project. Problem is, When after run test cases, VS instances open by each test cases. How can i run multiple test cases in one VS instance.

Comment: Can you report with other applications? Is it related to Visual Studio Extensions?

Comment: Yes, This is related for Visual Studio Extensions. I did test cases for visual studio extensibility project.